# Objective-C, Repeat Same Operation but Rotated by 90 Degrees

Tags: objective-c, uikit

I have some code of which this is a tiny excerpt:

```
surfaceDimension = self.window.frame.size.height;
sliderDistancePerPoint = 1.0f / surfaceDimension / FINGER_RATIO;
addThisToSlider = sliderDistancePerPoint * diff * 1.6f;
```

In a subclass, I overwrite this method, and repeat the same code, but rotated:

```
surfaceDimension = self.window.frame.size.width;
sliderDistancePerPoint = 1.0f / surfaceDimension / FINGER_RATIO;
addThisToSlider = sliderDistancePerPoint * diff * 1.6f;
```

What are the (various) ways that I can virtualize this code so that it can work in either orientation? I can of course make `surfaceDimension` into a method, but I would need to repeat this for all the dependencies. Other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using standard OO practices and making the methods general enough you can get this moving pretty easily. It's a pretty decent use of inheritance

```
// override in subclass
- (BOOL) useXOrientation {
    return NO;
}

- (CGPoint) setOriginFrom:(CGPoint)sourcePoint to:(CGPoint)targetPoint {
    if (self.useXOrientation)
        targetPoint.x = sourcePoint.x;
    else
        targetPoint.y = sourcePoint.y;
    return targetPoint;
}



- (float) sizeOfDimension:(CGSize)size {
    if (self.useXOrientation)
        return size.width;
    else
        return size.height;
}

// example method
- (void) resetFirstTouch:(CGPoint)point {
    self.firstTouch = [self setOriginFrom:point to:self.firstTouch];
    self.firstTouchInParent = [self setOriginFrom:[self convertPoint:self.firstTouch toView:self.superview] to:self.firstTouchInParent];
}
```